# Match rows for value in specific columns and paste matched/unmatched rows in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I got data in sheet1 and sheet2, which i want to copy and paste in sheet3. That is already done. So next i want to match rows, by checking column C, D, E, H and I. The C and H column value is integer and the rest is text/strings.

If two rows match, then i want to copy and paste one of the lines in a new third sheet, and add the integer difference from column H in column H (The difference will be 0 if the lines match in all columns)

If the two rows dont match, copy and paste one of the lines in a new fourth sheet, and add the integer difference from column H in column H

The code so far:

```
Sub CopyPasteSheet()

    Dim mySheet, arr

    arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
    Const targetSheet = "Sheet3"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each mySheet In arr
        Sheets(mySheet).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
            With Sheets(targetSheet)
                .Range("A1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
                If mySheet <> arr(UBound(arr)) Then .Rows(1).Delete xlUp
            End With
    Next mySheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "So next i want to match rows" - rows from which sheets ? " in a new third sheet" ? you already have 3 sheets. "if the two rows dont match, copy and paste one of the lines in a new fourth sheet" - line from which sheet ?

Comment: I want to match all rows in sheet1 with all rows in sheet2. If there is a match in all the columns, including the amount, then copy and paste one of the matched rows in sheet3. If all columns but column H match, then copy paste to sheet4 and overwrite column H and state the amount difference there is between the two rows from sheet1 and sheet2. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: OK, how many rows, more that 10,000 ? and how many characters in the largest text string ?

Comment: The text string varies from time to time but the longest string for this data input is 22 characters without space characters and 25 characters with space. And rows is not near 10.000. So not more than 10.000 :). I have answered below what i have made until now (with help).

Comment: Okay see new answer

Comment: I can't see the values in Column E on sheet3 and sheet4. Why is row 2 blank on sheet4 it should be random name 3 with diff of 7. Were sheets 3 and 4 clear before you ran it ?

Comment: Yes they were. Tried again by deleting the data in sheet3 and sheet4, and then ran it again. Still the same

Answer (score 0):

Code so far, but i receive a code error "Application-defined or object-defined error". It does copy the rows which match into a new sheet and state the difference as 0 in column H, but it doesn't work for the ones that dont match.

```
Sub MatchRows()
    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant, d As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim dic As Object, ky As String

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    a = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).Value
    b = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:I" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).Value
    ReDim c(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 2))
    ReDim d(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 2))

    For i = 1 To UBound(b, 1)
        ky = b(i, 3) & "|" & b(i, 4) & "|" & b(i, 5) & "|" & b(i, 9)
        dic(ky) = i
    Next

    For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
        ky = a(i, 3) & "|" & a(i, 4) & "|" & a(i, 5) & "|" & a(i, 9)
        If dic.exists(ky) Then
            j = dic(ky)
            If a(i, 8) = b(j, 8) Then
                k = k + 1
                For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    c(k, n) = a(i, n)
                Next
                c(k, 8) = 0
            Else
                m = m + 1
                For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    d(k, n) = a(i, n)
                Next
                d(k, 8) = a(i, 8) - b(j, 8)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Resize(k, UBound(a, 2)).Value = c
    Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Resize(m, UBound(a, 2)).Value = d
End Sub
```

Comment: Do Sheet3 and Sheet4 have existing data on them ?

Comment: No they dont have data until it gets pasted

Comment: Why `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2) etc`, is there a header line ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the performance is too slow remove the complexity of arrays by writing to the output sheets one line at a time.

Update - copy complete line

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MatchRows2()

    Dim dic As Object, key As String
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, s As String, diff As Long
    Dim iRow3 As Long, iRow4 As Long, i As Long, t0 As Single
    Dim rng As Range
    t0 = Timer
    s = "|"

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' sheet 2
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
       key = ws.Cells(i, "C") & s & ws.Cells(i, "D") _
             & s & ws.Cells(i, "E") & s & ws.Cells(i, "I")
       If dic.exists(key) Then
           MsgBox "Duplicate key '" & key & "'", vbCritical, "Sheet2 Row " & i
           Exit Sub
       Else
          dic.Add key, ws.Cells(i, "H")
       End If
    Next
    Debug.Print dic.Count

    ' results
    Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
    iRow3 = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
    iRow4 = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
    'sheet 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
       key = ws.Cells(i, "C") & s & ws.Cells(i, "D") _
             & s & ws.Cells(i, "E") & s & ws.Cells(i, "I")
       If dic.exists(key) Then
           diff = ws.Cells(i, "H") - dic(key)
           If diff = 0 Then
               iRow3 = iRow3 + 1
               Set rng = ws3.Cells(iRow3, "A")
           Else
               iRow4 = iRow4 + 1
               Set rng = ws4.Cells(iRow4, "A")
           End If
           ws.Rows(i).Copy rng
           rng.Offset(0, 7).Value = diff ' col H
       End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: it says "type mismatch" in diff = ws.Cells(i, "H") - dic(key)

Comment: @Anonymous Are all the values in Columns H integers, no blanks ? Is row 1 a header ?

Comment: A row is all headers and yeah from H2:H5 there is values and all is integers

Comment: @Anony Change `For i = 1 To iLastRow` to `For i = 2 To iLastRow`

Comment: Nice! it works, but would it be possible to copy the entire row instead of only the columns that match? Like if the specific columns match then copy and paste entire row. Its already a big help!

Comment: Damn it works better now, why does it copy both lines when its a match and just the one when there isnt? I want it like the one where the amount doesnt match. So only copy one row. Its perfect in sheet4 where there is a difference but in sheet3 where the difference is 0, it copies both lines insted of just one?

Comment: @Anony both lines ? You would have to post screenshots of sheet1 and sheet2 for me to explain that.